# Textarea.textcontent is not changing

Tags: javascript, html, textarea

I have a select object whose onChange event is calling this method:

```
 function universeChange()
 {

var select = document.getElementById("universeSelect");


form = document.getElementById("textAreaUniverse");

//form.textContent = universeDict[select.selectedIndex].value;
form.textAreaValue = universeDict[select.selectedIndex].value;

 }
```

When I am debugging in developer tools the textContent value changes as it should change but the clients end doesn't reflect the new values.  I have this feeling that I am not using the correct method to change the value of the textarea?

Comment: You'd want to attach a onChange listener for the textarea and listen to `event.target.value`

Comment: @TonyTaiNguyen, I will give that a shot and let you know if it works, thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Have you tried using the .value attribute to change the text?

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_textarea_value.asp

Comment: That did it, and now I fell really stupid.  Strange how they have so many attributes that appear like they all do the same thing.

Comment: No worries, that's why we have things like Stack Overflow! :)